# Bypassing 'Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined'

Tags: java, closures, processbuilder

I have the following code, but when I declare the String line outside of the new Thread class I get an exception. I'm from a C# background, so I understand now that Java does not support true closures. So my question is:

How can I declare a string outside of new Thread and use it in new Thread?

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable line inside an inner class defined
>   in a different method

```
ProcessBuilder builder =
    new ProcessBuilder("/Users/Joe/Desktop/file", "-i", src);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = builder.start();
final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
String line;
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
                line += br.readLine() + "\n";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }               
}).start();
```

Comment: Make it final: final String line = "";

Comment: Except that TS wants to assign new String objects to their variable.

Comment: can't make it final. Need to assign to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `line` to be a `StringBuilder` and declare it as `final`.  Then change the `run()` method to append to the `StringBuilder`.

Provided that you `join()` the child thread before you attempt to read `line` in the main thread, you don't need to use a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: The problem is not how to add text to the StringBuilder but **when** it's available, because the thread may take a long time to fill the StringBuilder. A rendez-vous is needed (CountDownLatch need)

Comment: @Aubin - or a `join` call, like I suggested.

Comment: @Omid - The cause of the NPE's is the logic of your `while` loop.  Each call to `readLine()` reads a line.  The way that you are using it will result in NPEs if the number of lines read is odd.  Think about it ....

Comment: yes but I still can't get the value of StringBuilder from outside of the thread class. If I do System.out.println(line.toString()); inside of the class it's fine. But outside of the class it does not return anything. As if it's cleared.

Comment: Did you add the code to the parent thread to `join()` the child thread after it has finished?  The `join()` call will ensure that the two threads will synchronize and all changes made to the `StringBuilder` by the child thread are visible to the parent thread.  Without the `join` the parent may see stale state, and it may attempt to read `line` before the child has finished (or even started) reading the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

1. create a new class dedicated to the reading of the Process output (implements [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html))
2. waiting to the instance of its class (a *job*) before using it's result with [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) methods.

Here is a code sample:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class FutureJob {

   static class StreamToString implements Callable< String > {

      BufferedReader br;

      public StreamToString( InputStream in ) {
         br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in ));
      }

      @Override public String call() throws Exception {
         StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder( 1024 );
         String line;
         while(( line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
            buffer.append( line );
            buffer.append( '\n' );
         }
         br.close();
         return buffer.toString();
      }
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      ProcessBuilder   builder  = new ProcessBuilder( "cmd", "/C", "dir", "c:\\" );
      Process          process  = builder.start();
      ExecutorService  executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      StreamToString   toString = new StreamToString( process.getInputStream());
      Future< String > result   = executor.submit( toString );
      System.out.println( result.get());
      executor.shutdownNow();
   }
}
```

The blocking wait of the caller is made internally by `result.get()`, if necessary.

Comment: Actually, I have been looking for a way to read the output asynchronous so that I won't have to use the "Thread" class. This might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: how did you execute FutureJob?

Comment: executor.submit() and result.get() are part of the concurrency framework [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html)

Comment: no I mean, how did you initiate and run FutureJob? I just did it and it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Have you first, copy paste my [Short, Self Containd, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) before say it doesn't work? Execute it under debugger to observe it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another object which will hold and change the `String`. Make this object final and change the string using this object method.

You can try using `StringBuilder` as the final object and use its `append` function to modify the string.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, declare `line` as an instance variable inside the inner class, since you are not using it outside of the class anyway:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    String line;
    @Override public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
                line += br.readLine() + "\n";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }               
}).start();
```

Comment: eh? I am using it outside of the class. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: @Omid: not in the code that you posted. And it doesn't really make sense to use it outside of the class. What do you intend for it to do? Do you want to make changes to the variable inside that anonymous class and have it reflected in the outside method? Ignoring the fact you cannot assign to captured variables, even if you could, it would not work anyway because you are running the stuff inside the class on a separate thread, so it may not run (or be halfway running) before the outside method finishes anyway.

Comment: I want to use regex on line itself and get that value outside the class. I don't need line itself to be used outside the class, but I need the match of the regex. Of course I posted it like this to make it easier for people to understand..

Comment: @Omid: but my point is how can you possibly "get that value outside the class" when "outside the class" is in another thread?